# Closure default initializer missing - swift closure variable declaration?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, closures

I declared closure outside viewController class, I created one variable of that closure inside viewController class, but it shows the error of default initializer missing for this closure.

I understand the consequences about variable and constant declaration and default initialization have to be assigned at the time of declaration. but I unable to understand what could be the default initialization of my closure, I tried bunch of few tricks to solve it but didn't worked out.

Here is my closure declaration

```
typealias completionBlock = (String) -> ()
```

and here is my variable declaration of that closure, which prompting to initialize it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     var completionHandler: completionBlock = // What could be the default initializer to this closure

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
     }
}
```

I want to achieve calling this block whenever I gets those values required to pass, Same as objective-c external completionBlock declaration.

Comment: just delcare it as `completionBlock?` or `completionBlock!` (if you are 100% sure it will be set)

Comment: It fires - 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value', when I'm trying to call - completionHandler("completion")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 3 Options

- default property:

  ```
  var completionHandler : completionBlock = { _ in }
  ```
- Implicitly unwrapped Optional - only do this when you are 100% sure a value will be set before ever calling the `completionHandler`:

  ```
  var completionHandler: completionBlock!
  ```
- "regular" Optional

  ```
  var completionHandler: completionBlock?

  // later callable via
  completionHandler?("hi")
  ```

Comment: Thanks Luk, my question's answer is your first case - default property of closure, that's what exactly I wanted to know. One more help luck if you don't mind, can you please let me know from where you learnt these things so deep? as I tried to explore apple documents but I didn't find out a solution so far.

Comment: @KiranJasvanee I did not learn it anywhere, I started answering swift questions and programming in swift. I did not read a single tutorial. In your case you simply have to provide a closure. The closure argument does not matter, therefore `_`, the body should be empty there there is no body, that is all.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this?

```
var completionHandler: completionBlock = { stringValue  in 
        // but your code here
    }
```

Comment: Hello Ismail, I appreciate your answer. luk2302 has given a current answer for which I was looking for. I wanted to know a default initialization property of closure, as for array it's [] and for int is 0.